# Can I use Azure memory cache outside of the emulator, primarily for development purposes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, azure

I'd like to start my development with Azure Cache in ASP.NET MVC4 and want to put my session in an in-memory cache, and later have it work with Azure Cache.

My goal is to develop on my laptop without incurring the overhead and delay in building my site and having to deploy an Azure Compute instance each time I build.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote my own caching interface called ICache that did most of the caching functions.  Then I  that used the HttpContext cache instead of Azure cache based on the build type.  I created a new build type of "Local", and used a #if Local #else #endif.

There are some subtle differences, but for the most part, it works great.  I can run my MVC app outside of the emulator, which is insanely faster.

... but I have to ask, why are you putting session in cache??

Comment: Why in cached? I'd like to have stateless servers.  Is there a better way?  I forget everything about MVC

Comment: Cache isn't stateless.  It will remove items based on how full it gets and how long something has been in the cache.  You can set ASP.Net to save the session to SQL if you have that ability.  That'd be your best bet, then it doesn't expire.

Comment: MSFT seems to be promoting my concept... unless I'm misunderstanding  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx

Comment: Interesting... thanks for sharing that link!  I didn't know Azure had that capability.

Comment: Seems that I can use this in Amazon... and therefore not use Azure VM at all.